# How to instantiate/inject class declared in main component to another component

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

My AppComponent sample:

```
   ///other imports here    
   import { ApplyColor } from './../../shared/directives/applycolor';
   import { SomeComponent} from './../../components/somecomponent';


    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        directives: [ApplyColor, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
        providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
        templateUrl: 'myurl.html'
    })

    @RouteConfig([
      //routes here
      { path: '/main', name: 'Main', component: SomeComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    ])

    export class AppComponent {

    }
```

In order to instantiate `ApplyColor` in `SomeComponent`

- Import `ApplyColor`
- Add to `directives: [ApplyColor]`
- Instantiate with a `new` keyword

Which is:

```
 import {Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
 import { ApplyColor  } from './../../shared/directives/applycolor';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    directives: [ApplyColor],
    templateUrl: 'app/components/mycomponenturl.html'
})

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var color = new ApplyColor();
        color.apply(2);
     }
}
```

How can I instantiate/inject `ApplyColor` without there 3 steps above?

Comment: This way you have to use sharedservice with single instance shared.

Comment: @micronyks I think it is something mentioned on one of the answers. Is there any articles on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive instances are managed by Angular2. This means that you only need to specify it into the `directives` attribute. So if `ApplyColor` is a directive just add it into the `directives` attribute.

If `ApplyColor` isn't a directive, you can explicitly instantiate into the provide to the child component using `@Input`.

In your case, it's a bit particular since you leverage routing. In this case, you need to rely on a shared service. Such service needs to be defined when bootstrapping the application to be able to share a single instance for all components. You can set your instance of `ApplyColor` into a field of this service. So both component (`AppComponent` and `SomeComponent`) can access it.

- Define the service

  ```
  export class SharedService {
    color:ApplyColor;
  }
  ```
- Bootstrapping the service

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedService ]);
  ```
- Set `color` from `AppComponent`

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private service:SharedService) {
      var color = new ApplyColor();
      this.service.color = color;
    }
  }
  ```
- Get `color` from `SomeComponent`

  ```
  @Component({
    (...)
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private service:SharedService) {
      this.service.color.apply(2);
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you give some more details on that?

Comment: I updated my answer with more details for the last option. Feel free to tell me if this suits you.

Comment: Great thanks for that. So basically it is bad idea to share `directive` instead it is better to use shared `service` if I understand correctly...

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, you can't "share" directives. You can provide data to children directives from the parent component using `@Input`. When defining two directives into two different components won't correspond to the same instances...

Answer (score 1):

I have just started working angular2 but as I can understand:

import ApplyColor => you can't remove that, it required by the compiler to know which class you are referenced to

directives : [ApplyColor] => that means you will use the selector (the one you have defined in applycolor.ts) in the template (app/components/mycomponenturl.html). it is only to know where the component will be in the view.

new ApplyColor => you are creating the object yourself, it is not injected. 
To inject your component,

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private color:ApplyColor) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.color.apply(2);
  }
}
```

I hope it helped you ?

Comment: Yeah I come up whit this just now too. Also I have import statement on top `import { ApplyColor  } from './../../shared/directives/applycolor';`